# Connection between several GUIs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My aim is two connect two system (S1 and S2). Each one is built in a GUI created using Swing. In order to create a bridge between them (B0) I am trying to create another GUI that calls the S1 GUI, but I am not able to extract data obtained after running (S1). How could I create a connection between them in order to extract variables created while running S1 GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need some way for the applications to communicate with eachother, you could ue sockets, or a database, or if you want something more enterprisey, you could use [JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdx.html) or [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)  (Which actually implements JMS and several other protocols)

Comment: I think I explain it beter here--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870512/one-guis-output-another-guis-input-in-java?noredirect=1#comment70923797_41870512

Comment: What i said here still applies to that situation, either a database or some sort of inter-process messaging system like ActiveMQ or ZeroMQ or JMS

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that one of the possibilities is to create a Model-View-Controller design pattern in which you define all the data and stuff needed to create the GUI and you can have access to it from another GUI. 
If it is too much work and you really need only specific data, the best way to transfer it is using JSON.