# One GUI's OUTPUT another GUI's input in java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, connection

I have two projects(P1 & P2) which are two different systems, each one has its GUI (GUI1 & GUI2). GUI1's output must be GUI2's input. In order to pass all the information from GUI1 to GUI2, I have added P1 as a dependent project of P2. With this, I have access to all the functions in P1 but I can´t get the modified data created after running GUI1( GUI1 is package of P1). As you can see GUI1 has several tabs in which loaded data from external files is modified and  new variables/data is created while running GUI1.

[image: GUI's structure, serveral tabs].

All the information displayed in GUI1 should be the input of GUI2 in order to modify it.

[image: GUI's input tab]

Could you let me know how I can pass all teh data from GUI1 to GUI2?
I would be really pleased if you could help me as I am new programming in Java and I really dont find any way to make it.

Comment: Don't think GUI -> pass to -> GUI. Think GUI -> pass to -> common model -> GUI

Comment: Ho would do in order to create a common model that is able to store all the data from GUI1 and then access from GUI2? I have no idea how this shoud be done. And is it appropiate to add P1 as dependent project of P2?

Comment: At first stage thing in terms of single program. Swing philosophy of model hard to describe in comment.

Comment: More on Swing models [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: Databases are one way to share data, or some kind of middleware - passing events between apps.

Comment: If all the information of P1 is displayed in the last tab of the GUI1, making the MVC model of the last tab would be enough to get access to that data from GUI2?